# Странное поведение переключателя страниц

Tags: jquery, php, codeigniter, sql

Добрый вечер. Есть переключатель страниц на codeigniter:

контроллер:

```
function page($param1 = '', $param2 = '', $param3 = '', $param4 = '') {
            $config['base_url'] = '/admin/news/page';
            $config['per_page'] = 10;
            $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('news');
            $this->pagination->initialize($config); 
            $page_data['pages'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
            $page_data['news'] = $this->news_model->news( $config['per_page'] ,$this->uri->segment(4));
            $this->load->view('admin/index', $page_data);

    }
```

модель:

```
function news($num, $offset) {
        $this->db->order_by('id' , 'desc');
        $news = $this->db->get('news',$num, $offset);
        return $news->result_array();
    }
```

вид:

```
<?php echo $pages;?>
```

Проблема: переключатель не работает, когда контроллер news находится в папке admin, то есть controller/admin/news.php
Переключатель работает 100%, когда находится просто в  папке controller, то есть controller/news.php
В чем может быть проблема? Никак не разберусь. Вот уже недели 2 думаю. ((
Как это может быть связано с тем, что контроллер в папке?

Answer (score 1):

Строчку

```
$config['base_url'] = '/admin/news/page';
```

попробуй заменить на

```
$config['base_url'] = 'admin/news/page';
```

Comment: Попробовал, но дело не в этом. Даже если абсолютный адрес использую. Проблема именно в том, что `$this->pagination->create_links()` неправильно генерируется, если контроллер именно в папке.

`$this->uri->segment(N)` прописан верно.
Пагинатор будто не видит сегмент admin.